# How to work around the ordered analytical nested function cannot be nested error?

Tags: sql, function, nested, teradata

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id
      ,rep_date
      ,MIN(rep_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS min_date
      ,level 
      ,COALESCE(max(CASE WHEN min_date = rep_date THEN level END) OVER (PARTITION BY id), level) AS start_level
FROM database
```

Here a single id has several rep_dates with corresponding level. I first create a variable that has earliest rep_date at every entry and now I want to create a variable that has the corresponding level of the earliest rep_date in every entry.

This results in the error: "Ordered Analytical Functions can not be nested". How can I solve this?

Comment: You need a *Derived Table* or *CTE*. But it looks like you want the result of a `first_value(level) over (partition by id order by rep_date)`